# Taylor's Theorem with Lagrange Remainder

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose I want to show that :

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} = f'(x)+\frac{h^2}{6}f'''(\alpha)$$

where $\alpha \in [x-h,x+h]$

Now Using Taylor's Theorem with the Lagrange Remainder I know that

$f(x) = f(x_0) + (x-x_o)f'(x_o) +\frac{(x-x_o)^2}{2} \; f''(\alpha) \; \;$ where $x>x_o$ and $\alpha \in [x_o,x]$

and so by replacing $x_o$ with $x$ and $x$ with $x+h$

$f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) +\frac{h^2}{2} \; f''(\alpha) \; \;$ where  $\alpha \in [x,x+h]$

How do I do something similiar for $f(x-h)$ and conclude after joining the equations that the combined $\alpha \in [x-h,x+h]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Taylor's Theorem you get
$$
 f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}2 f''(x) + \frac{h^3}6 f'''(\alpha) 
\quad \text{for some } \alpha \in (x, x+h)
$$ and $$
 f(x-h) = f(x) - hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}2 f''(x) - \frac{h^3}6 f'''(\beta) 
\quad \text{for some } \beta \in (x-h, x) \, .
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}2 = hf'(x) + \frac{h^3}6 \frac{f'''(\alpha)+f'''(\beta)}2 \, .
$$
Assuming that $f'''$ is continuous, it follows from the  intermediate value theorem that
$$
 \frac{f'''(\alpha)+f'''(\beta)}2 = f'''(\gamma)
\quad \text{for some } \gamma \in [\beta, \alpha] \subset (x-h, x+h) \, .
$$